# Why of this bound $||u_{m0}|| \leq ||u_0||$, where $u_{m0}$ is a projection of $u_0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, galerkin-methods

I'm dealing with Navier-Stokes equations, using the book of Teman. Theres a bound of a projection of a function that i didn't understood, so i will introduce the main concepts with i am dealing with.

Consider $u_m=\sum_{i=1}^m g_{im}(t)w_i$ an approximation of $u$ via galerkin method, where $w_i$ are the basis and $g_{im}(t)$ the coeficients, $u_m(0)=u_{m0}$ and $u(0)=u_0$.

The space $V$ is basecally the closure, in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, of the set of all function $C^\infty$ with support on a open set  $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, with it's divergent being null.

Let $\{w_j\}$ be a base of $V$ which we can take $u_{m0}$ as a projection in $V$ of $u_0$ spanned by $w_1,w_2, \cdots,w_m $.

So, why this bound is valid,
$||u_{m0}|| \leq ||u_0||$?

$||\cdot|| $ is the norm in $H^1_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in the context of Galerkin method, "base" of a separable normed space $X$ means a linearly indpendent countable set whose span is dense in $X$ (the existence of this family follows from the separability - see Lemma 4.1, p. 83, in [Le Dret](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YWo_AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&dq=On+proc%C3%A8de+par+%C3%A9tapes+en+suivant+la+philosophie+esquiss%C3%A9e+plus+haut.&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbk-XZveTeAhXsAMAKHVi8AmAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=On%20proc%C3%A8de%20par%20%C3%A9tapes%20en%20suivant%20la%20philosophie%20esquiss%C3%A9e%20plus%20haut.&f=false)). On the other hand, in the context of Hilber spaces, "base" usually means a maximal orthonormal set which is characterized as follows:

> **Theorem.** Let $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$ be an orthonormal family in a Hilbert space $H$. The following assertions are equivalent:
>
> - $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$ is maximal.
> - $ x=\sum_{j\in J}(x,e_j)e_j$ for all $x\in \mathcal{H}$.
> - $ \|x\|^2=\sum_{j\in J}|(x,e_j)|^2$ for all $x\in \mathcal{H}$.
> - $\overline{\operatorname{span}\{e_j\mid j\in J\}}=\mathcal{H}$.

*Proof:* See Corollary 12.8, p. 532, in [Knapp](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4ZZCAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA532&dq=%22is+maximal+among+orthonormal+subsets+of%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitw5XYwuTeAhXIA8AKHZ52CIoQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20maximal%20among%20orthonormal%20subsets%20of%22&f=false) and Proposition 2.3, p. 479, in [Taylor](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vISPd8QJfHoC&pg=PA479&lpg=PA479&dq=%22maximal+if+and+only+if+its+linear+span+is+dense+in%22&source=bl&ots=tT5DoSCHBQ&sig=gYA2coVDiGbkePZMjPX7ZJLXpbU&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYueW2xuTeAhVRTsAKHVK-A_YQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22maximal%20if%20and%20only%20if%20its%20linear%20span%20is%20dense%20in%22&f=false).

From this theorem, if $X$ is Hilbert separable, then a base in the "Hilbert space sense" is also a base in the "Galerking sense".

Therefore, assuming that $(w_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ is base of $V$ (which is Hilbert separable) in the "Hilbert space sense", using the above theorem we conclude that

$$\begin{aligned}
\|u_{m0}\|^2&=(u_{m0},u_{m0})\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^m(u_0,w_i)w_i,\sum_{j=1}^m(u_0,w_j)w_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m(u_0,w_i)\sum_{j=1}^m\overline{(u_0,w_j)}\left(w_i,w_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m|(u_0,w_i)|^2\left(w_i,w_i\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m|(u_0,w_i)|^2\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty|(u_0,w_i)|^2\\
&=\|u_0\|^2
\end{aligned}$$